# Rails redirect_to another controller method throwing "Template missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I gotta be missing something. I have a controller action for short urls:

```
def shorturl
   redirect_to :action => show, :id => Base58.decode(params[:id]) and return
end
```

My intention is have this either redirect or load the regular show method of the same controller. At this point, I don't care which way, just want to get it working first.

The problem is it throws a missing template error like its not exiting the shorturl method.

```
Missing template controller/shorturl with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb, :rjs]}
```

The console shows the query from show is executing so it seems its doing the redirect but still staying inside the method and expecting a view for shorturl instead of the redirected method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal, and go to project directory and type

```
   rake routes
```

Will let you know about the various paths generated from your routes file.

then redirect using

```
redirect_to xyz_path(:id=> Base58.decode(params[:id]))
return
```

Edit:--

redirect and render are too different things.

```
redirect_to(:action=>’my_action’)
```

will send a 302 redirect request to your browser, the consequence being that any existing variables are lost [2], and the action called ‘my_action’ will be executed.

```
render(:action=>’my_action’)
```

will NOT execute the code in the action called ‘my_action’ [1]. It will render the view only. Existing variables will not be lost.

Comment: The routes didn't have anything to do with it but xyz_path DID work. Technically this is solved but I still think its not the proper way because it shouldn't have to redirect outside the controller, in a way. `redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => id` **should** have the same result.

Comment: @user478798 its one of the same thing. different ways to solve a problem. Main point is it should not effect the performance.